# OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS keychain flag ignored?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild, codesign

I have just learned about the possibility to use OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS to specify the keychain which includes the cert needed for building and signing an app. But unfortunately I cannot get it to work.

My script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="MyProject"
CONFIGURATION="Release"
SDK="iphoneos"
IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: John Doe (XX22RR22O)"
KEYCHAIN="/Users/username/Library/Keychains/someKeyChain.keychain"
PASSWORD=""

security unlock-keychain -p ${PASSWORD} ${KEYCHAIN}
xcodebuild -target "${TARGET}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk $SDK CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${IDENTITY}" OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain ${KEYCHAIN}"
```

But that fails:

```
Check dependencies
[BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: John Doe (XX22RR22O)' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

But if I switch to the keychain first it works but that is not useable on a build server where multiple builds could happen simultaneously:

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="MyProject"
CONFIGURATION="Release"
SDK="iphoneos"
IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: John Doe (XX22RR22O)"
KEYCHAIN="/Users/username/Library/Keychains/someKeyChain.keychain"
PASSWORD=""

security unlock-keychain -p ${PASSWORD} ${KEYCHAIN}
security default-keychain -s ${KEYCHAIN}
xcodebuild -target "${TARGET}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk $SDK CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${IDENTITY}" OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain ${KEYCHAIN}"
```

Hope you guys can help
-Morten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to upgrade: Xcode 4.3 respects the `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS` flag during the `Check dependencies` build step.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay :)

Answer (score 5):

I found that if I didn't add the keychain to keychain search list, xcodebuild would not respect the `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAG --keychain` setting. I had to add this code:

```
// Early in the script
ORIGINAL_KEYCHAINS=`security list-keychains -d user`

// After I create my keychain, add it to the list
security list-keychains -d user -s ${ORIGINAL_KEYCHAINS} "${KEYCHAIN_NAME}"

// On cleanup
security list-keychains -d user -s ${ORIGINAL_KEYCHAINS}
```

Needless to say, I lost hours figuring this out.

Also of help, making sure the keychain stays open for the length of your build. As [advised here](http://modeset.com/what-we-know/2013/03/11/jenkins_keychain_timeouts):

```
security -v set-keychain-settings -lut 7200 ${KEYCHAIN_NAME}
```

Comment: This is super helpful, but I found that the list of user keychains in `ORIGINAL_KEYCHAINS` contained apostrophes for each one; running that variable through code like `CLEAN_KEYCHAINS="${ORIGINAL_KEYCHAINS//\"}"` (it replaces all apostrophes with nothing) when doing the cleanup worked flawlessly.

Comment: Great insight, but the syntax is a bit outdated. As pointed out in the previous comment, be careful with the quotes and spaces in the output

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem while trying to set up CI for our iOS projects. I ended up updating the `PackageApplication` Perl script to support passing a keychain option. Location:

```
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication
```

I'm still waiting for some licensing clarification from Apple so that I can publish my updated script to GitHub.

Comment: Sounds interesting, please let me know when you know more.

Comment: Were you ever able to publish this?

Answer (score 0):

None of these really works unless you have the simplest of scripted builds going. Like @Tyler said, PackageApplication doesn't support specifying the keychain, and some versions of xcode will require there be no duplicate certificates across keychains when they check dependencies.

Don't waste your times, just call Apple and ask them to rename one of your certificates (they will actually rename your company --- by appending a suffix --- and you just have to regenerate your certificates and update your profiles).