# How to pass keychain to "Check dependencies" step of xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, xcodebuild, codesign

I'm building an iPhone application with the iOS5 SDK and signing it from the command line and signing it with a certificate in my non-default keychain. Everything works fine if I make that keychain the default, but without it it fails on the "Check dependencies" step since it is searching the default keychain.

While the `codesign` step uses `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS`, the "Check dependencies" step does not. This may just be a bug of Apple's, and it should respect those flags when checking.

1. How can I specify the keychain to search during the "Check dependencies step?
2. Failing that, how can I hack on the "Check dependencies" step?
3. Failing that, how can I skip the "Check dependencies" step entirely?

This is same problem as expressed in [OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS keychain flag ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399134/other-code-sign-flags-keychain-flag-ignored), but the one answer given is unfortunately not helpful to me; I am signing during `xcodebuild`, not `xcrun PackageApplication`, so hacking on that file won't fix the issue.

```
$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 4.2
Build version 4C199
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Any solutions???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found no solution for Xcode 4.2, but this appears fixed in 4.3. Upgrade!

Comment: This seems to be an issue in Mavericks under xcode 5 too. I think that's what I'm seeing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887883/cant-use-my-own-kestore-with-xcodebuild-under-mavericks