# Can't use my own kestore with xcodebuild under Mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, codenameone, xcodebuild

I'm trying to migrate some iOS xcode build servers to use Mavericks which is essential for xcode 6 builds. However, invoking xcodebuild with code that used to work in mountain lion just doesn't seem to work anymore and results in:

```
Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities 
(i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile 
specified in your build settings (“provision name”) were found.
```

Our build command is pretty standard and the certificate is in place, doing this exact same code on mountain lion "just works" (notice I added line breaks for readability and replaced some private data such as project name and provisioning):

```
/Applications/Xcode5.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project ProjectName.xcodeproj/
-alltargets -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos7.0 build 
PROVISIONING_PROFILE=XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: name of company (XXXXXXXX)" 
KEYCHAIN=/Users/administrator/Library/Keychains/temp.keychain OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS=--keychain /Users/administrator/Library/Keychains/temp.keychain
```

I have a workaround that signs with a "known working" certificate/provisioning and replaces them using the codesign tool after the build completes but that is causing some side effects to the users that I have no idea how to workaround. As far as I can tell the above should work and might just be missing a new argument to xcodebuild that I am unaware of.

Comment: Weird thing is when I run locally with the exact same setup this seems to work? I have no explanation for this...

Comment: This seems to be related to the temp keychain argument being ignored but I have no idea why? When I issue security list-keychains the temp keychain isn't there despite the fact that I issued security commands to unlock and make it the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mavericks ignores the keychain set default when invoking:

```
security default-keychain
```

And the initial xcodebuild checking logic ignores the command line keychain arguments!

The following command:

```
security list-keychains
```

Won't return the keychain you set. The workaround is actually simple:

```
security list-keychains -s /path/to/your/keychain
```

And then the right certificate will be found by the initial checking process.